# Get list of chatter groups in which user is member?

Tags: community, chatter-groups

I am new to salesforce. I want to display user's list of groups in which he is member in a community via homepage component.Does anyone know how to do that in visaulforce page.I am not sure about how to take current logged in user's Id and search the chatter groups for that user as member.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to query CollabrationGroupMember Object to find the record

```
List<CollaborationGroupMember> collGroupMemberList = [SELECT Id,CollaborationGroupId FROM CollaborationGroupMember WHERE MemberId= :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
```

Comment: Thank you Tushar, this will give me Id's of the groups, but how to find name and link of the groups from this query.Which object i should query for that?and how do i display this in VF page?Thanks

Comment: CollabrationGroup is the object which you need and to display in vf page you need to study  you can use apex:repeat and create table